# Vuforia stop the video in the Background

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am building an AR project using Unity and Meta 2 glasses. I am using Vuforia to detect an object when I add the vuforia packages to the project and run it I see like a video in the background. It is so distracting and could not manage to disable it.

[See a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrTz8.jpg)

Any clue how to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the Vuforia version you have recognizes your specific AR device, Vuforia thinks it is a phone and renders the video background. All you have to do is not to render the video background.

Here you can find the exact instructions of how to disable the rendering of the background in Unity:
[Disabling video background](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/unity-how-can-i-disable-video-background)

The important code is this:

```
BackgroundPlaneBehaviour bgPlane = GetComponent<BackgroundPlaneBehaviour> ();
if (bgPlane.enabled) {
    bgPlane.enabled = false;
}
```